# where must be break in switch objective-c

Tags: objective-c, switch-statement, case, break

What is the difference between this solution:

```
switch (value)
{
    case 1:
    {
        // some code
    } break;
}
```

When `break` stay after brackets
And this:

```
switch (value)
{
    case 1:
    {
        // some code
        break;
    }
}
```

When `break` stay in brackets

Comment: It doesn't matter.

Comment: @Sulthan thank you!

Comment: @Fogmeister they may be required if //some code initializes some variable

Comment: @hariszaman oh, objective-c... sorry, just saw that.

Comment: @hariszaman It's not **initialization** but **declaration** that requires the block syntax (braces).

Answer (score 9):

A `break` makes the `switch` statement to end its execution. If you don't add a `break` to your `case`, the next `case` will start executing. Consider:

```
NSInteger myInt = 0;
switch (myInt) {
case 0:
   NSLog("0");
case 1:
   NSLog("1");
default:
   NSLog("Default");
}
```

will print:

```
0
1
Default
```

because there are no breaks.

It doesn't matter if you wrap `break` into a block `{ break; }` because the block changes the scope of variables declared inside of it but has no effect on the `break` itself.

There is no difference between `{ ... } break;` and `{ ... break; }` because in both versions `break` is the last statement that is executed and that's all that matters.

However,

```
case 0:
   if (myCondition) {
      break;
   }
case 1:
   ...
```

would have a very different meaning. If `myCondition` is `NO`, then the next case (`case 1:`) is executed too (*fall-through*) because the `break` statement has not been executed.

Comment: This does not answer the question. Your comment ("It doesn't matter.") does, though.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe I think the paragraph in the middle answers the question. I am just trying to add some context.